# Match user input from ExchangeOnline

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

In PowerShell Exchange-online you can get the mailbox of a user from Get-Mailbox

If i then have the following user input.

```
$email = Read-Host -Prompt 'what email is it?'
```

How can i check the user input and see if it matches an existing mailbox and say "mailbox exists" if it exists, else the script should just stop running. How could this be done ?

Comment: Why not run `Get-Mailbox $email` after the input?

Comment: If i do that how can i make an if to check if it worked? if mailbox exist(from the input), else exit().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to approach this. One way it to store the mailbox search result into a variable. Then simply check if the variable actually stored anything.

```
$email = Read-Host -Prompt 'what email is it?'
$mailbox = Get-Mailbox $email -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($mailbox) {
    "Mailbox exists"
} else {
    Exit
}
```

`-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` is used to suppress the error that would be returned when the mailbox is not found.

---

A more sophisticated approach would be to catch the exception and take action accordingly.

```
$email = Read-Host -Prompt 'what email is it?'
try { 
    $mailbox = Get-Mailbox $email -ErrorAction Stop
    "Mailbox Exists"
} catch [System.Management.Automation.RemoteException] {
    Exit
}
```